# how to access object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function test(results) {
        //Populate the ComboBox with unique values

        var Gov;
        var values = [];
        var features = results.features;
        var og;
        for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {

            var aGOV = {
                "GovName": features[i].attributes.ENG_NAME,
                "GovNO": features[i].attributes.GOV_NO,
                "Shape": features[i].geometry
            }
           og = new Option(features[i].attributes.ENG_NAME, aGOV);
            var cbx = document.getElementById("cbxGov");
            cbx.options.add(og);
        }

    }

    function gov_selection_change() 
    {
        var cbx = document.getElementById("cbxGov");

        var itm = cbx.options[cbx.selectedIndex].value.hasOwnProperty("Shape");
    }
```

html code

```
<select id="cbxGov" onchange="gov_selection_change()">
```

My problem is i m not able to access property of aGOV  in my  `gov_selection_change(`)  function, it shows it has no such property, itm is false.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually trying to access any properties of `aGOV` in `goc_selection_change`, are you? If you did, it would be out of scope. Define `aGOV` outside of `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value property of an [HTMLOptionElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) always returns a DOMString (a.k.a. text), not an object.

So you have to save what you want to access in a lookup dictionary and then use the returned value as a lookup key.

```
var lookupDictionary = {};

function test(results) {
    var lookupKey,
        og;
    //...

    // don´t get the element in the loop
    var cbx = document.getElementById("cbxGov");

    //...

    for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        lookupKey = features[i].attributes.GOV_NO;

        lookupDictionary[lookupKey] = {
            "GovName": features[i].attributes.ENG_NAME,
            "GovNO": features[i].attributes.GOV_NO,
            "Shape": features[i].geometry
        }

        og = new Option(features[i].attributes.ENG_NAME, lookupKey );
        cbx.options.add( og );
    }
}

function gov_selection_change() {
    var cbx = document.getElementById("cbxGov");
    var key = cbx.options[cbx.selectedIndex].value;
    var itm = lookupDictionary[key].hasOwnProperty("Shape");
}
```

Comment: hye i need more help. can u tell me how can i remove  option from <select> using javascript . i need to refill them

Answer (score 0):

The variable `aGOV` is only available in the context of your `result()` function. If you want to use it from a different function declare it as a global variable.

Example:

```
var aGOV;

function result()
{
    // initialize aGOV
}

function gov_selection_change()
{
    // now you can access the aGOV variable
}
```